# overloaded constructor for FlinkKafkaProducer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm trying to use Scala and Flink to publish messages into a Kafka topic. However, when creating the FlinkKafkaProducer object using the code provided in [the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-producer), it tells me that the contructor cannot be applied. This is the code sample:

```scala
val studentProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer[String](
 "my_topic",                  // target topic
 new SimpleStringSchema(),    // serialization schema
 properties,                  // producer config
 FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE) // fault-tolerance
```

With the following imports:

```scala
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.{FlinkKafkaConsumer, FlinkKafkaProducer}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema

import java.util.Properties
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
/home/user/Flink/flinkproj/src/main/scala/org/flink/Job.scala:83:27: overloaded method constructor FlinkKafkaProducer with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: String,x$2: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.KafkaSerializationSchema[String],x$3: java.util.Properties,x$4: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic)org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer[String] <and>
[error]   (x$1: String,x$2: org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedSerializationSchema[String],x$3: java.util.Properties,x$4: java.util.Optional[org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.partitioner.FlinkKafkaPartitioner[String]])org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer[String] <and>
[error]   (x$1: String,x$2: org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedSerializationSchema[String],x$3: java.util.Properties,x$4: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic)org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer[String] <and>
[error]   (x$1: String,x$2: org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SerializationSchema[String],x$3: java.util.Properties,x$4: java.util.Optional[org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.partitioner.FlinkKafkaPartitioner[String]])org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer[String]
[error]  cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema, java.util.Properties, org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic)
[error]     val studentProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer[String](
```

The variable `properties` is an instance of `java.util.Properties`. I think it has to be in the String serializer, but I don't see what is wrong.

The details on the versions are the following, from the `build.sbt`:

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val flinkVersion = "1.11.3"

val flinkDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % flinkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % flinkVersion % "provided")
```

Comment: What imports did you use?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the original question with the information requested.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the documentation is out-of-date, and you need to either provide a `KafkaSerializationSchema` or a `KeyedSerializationSchema` -- or if you use a `SerializationSchema`, then you need to also supply a `FlinkKafkaPartitioner`.

I don't happen to have an example in Scala, but here's an example in Java showing how to implement a `KafkaSerializationSchema` that uses an `ObjectMapper` to write out JSON:

```java
/**
 * A Kafka {@link KafkaSerializationSchema} to serialize {@link ClickEventStatistics}s as JSON.
 *
 */
public class ClickEventStatisticsSerializationSchema implements KafkaSerializationSchema<ClickEventStatistics> {

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private String topic;

    public ClickEventStatisticsSerializationSchema(){
    }

    public ClickEventStatisticsSerializationSchema(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(
            final ClickEventStatistics message, @Nullable final Long timestamp) {
        try {
            //if topic is null, default topic will be used
            return new ProducerRecord<>(topic, objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(message));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not serialize record: " + message, e);
        }
    }
}
```